# No power to instrument fuse

Tags: electrical, oldsmobile, bravada

I have a '94 Oldsmobile Bravada and the digital dash quit working.  I found that I do not have power to the instrument fuse but have power to all other fuses in the panel.  I can not find an electrical diagram for my vehicle so I don't know where to start looking for the problem.

Comment: As a temporary fix for this, you could jump power over to the dead socket. If it still doesn't light, you have more serious problems.

Comment: You do need to find a wiring diagram for your vehicle. Try looking on the lines of Olds owners club sites. They may help you for a wiring diagram.

Comment: [The Haynes manual for your truck](http://www.haynes.com/products/productID/243) will have a wiring diagram. The books are cheap but, in my -- admittedly limited -- experience, reliable. The wiring diagrams they provide for my vehicle are essentially the same as those in the factory manual.

Comment: My "unclear" CV is based on two things: 1. Not sure if question was where to obtain a wiring diagram vs. how to solve the problem and 2. There is not enough information here to solve the problem and it is unlikely more will be added. My downvote is based on perceived lack of research looking for a wiring diagram.

Comment: @Rory Did you ever find the cause of this issue and do you recall what it was?

Answer (score 1):

A search on "[oldsmobile bravada wiring diagram](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=oldsmobile+bravada+wiring+diagram&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)" found a *lot* of images of wiring diagrams. You might be able to get started with one of those - what you'll be looking for is the schematic of the fuse panel to see where the power for the instrument panel fuse comes from. There are two likely possibilities:

1. That it comes from a common buss (the same place as all (or most) of the other fuses), or
2. That it is supplied separately perhaps with the ECU power ahead of the load reduction relay.

Once you know that you can see if there are other fuses that are powered from the same source and then check them see if they have power – if they do I would suspect damage to the fuse block itself, otherwise you'll want to troubleshoot the problem with the source.

As a quick test you could jump power from someplace else in the fuse panel to the hot (not load) side of the instrument cluster fuse – that will let you see if the panel will come up if it is powered.